# How to apply a javascript to my webView's html content in Android?

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

Im working on an epub reader for android platform. Not me started the project i just continue it so i have tons of code to get in to it.

My question is simple:

Is there a way in android to apply javascript to my html content inside my webView ?

I would like to make the html's font-size smaller or bigger by clicking a button for example... So users could modify font-size inside the webView.

Is there a way to achiev this ?

Any suggestions will be appreciated!

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way in android to apply javascript to my html content inside my webView ?

Given a `WebView` object named `wv`, execute:

```
wv.loadUrl("javascript:...");
```

where the `...` is the source code of the JavaScript to execute inside the context of the presently-displayed Web page. This is the same syntax used by bookmarklets in desktop browsers.

Note that you will also need to enable JavaScript in the first place, as described in nicholas.hauschild's answer.

Comment: And how can i properly use "" this mark inside my String for javascript ? Because if i start with "javascript:" there will be other " marks inside my javascript and it became mixed up with the string if you know what i mean...

Comment: @AdamVarhegyi: In Java, you escape embedded quotation marks with backslashes: http://www.javacoffeebreak.com/faq/faq0050.html

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is disabled by default on `WebView`'s.

To enable javascript in a `WebView`, you need to first get a hold of the `WebView`'s `WebSettings` member.  This can be done via a call to `getWebSettings()` on your `WebView`.

Once you have your `WebSettings`, you can call [`setJavaScriptEnabled(true)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setJavaScriptEnabled%28boolean%29) on it.

```
WebView webView = getWebView(); 
WebSettings webSettings = webView.getWebSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```